# Possibly Mysql 5.6.20 bug. Date - now()?

Tags: mysql

```
date_newOrd, now(), date_newOrd-now() AS `time`
```

this is my query. `date_newOrd` is type date. I try to calculate the time remaining for next arrival of order. I better show you the screenshot:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

the result is doesn't make any sense. What am i supposed to do>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot subtract dates like that:

```
mysql> select '2015-06-01 18:20:03' - now();
+-------------------------------+
| '2015-06-01 18:20:03' - now() |
+-------------------------------+
|               -20150602073525 |
+-------------------------------+
```

While that may look (vaguely) like a date, it's really an integer, and can't be used for further date math without extra processing.

You have to use [datediff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) or [timediff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
mysql> select timediff('2015-06-01 18:20:03', now()) as td, datediff('2015-06-01 18:20:03', now()) as dd;
+-----------+------+
| td        | dd   |
+-----------+------+
| -13:37:47 |   -1 |
+-----------+------+
```

note that `datediff` deals only with DATES, and `timediff` deals with datetime values.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a subtraction, MySQL is going to evaluate NOW() in a numeric context, it returns a numeric value.

```
SELECT NOW()+0 

20150602135210.000000
```

So, your statement is doing a subtraction of numbers, not doing a DATE calculation.

Some possibilities:

You could convert the datetime values into unix_timestamp values, (`UNIX_TIMESTMAP()` function) and then do a subtraction of those to get a difference in integer seconds.

The `DATEDIFF()` function would get you a difference in integer days. (That operates only on the date portion, it ignores the time... so that probably doesn't give you the resolution you are looking for.)

The `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` and `TIMEDIFF()` functions are also available. (The `TIMEDIFF` functions returns a `TIME` datatype value; the maximum value of that datatype is `838:59:59`, so that's limited to just under 35 days elapsed).

For example:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-06-03') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) AS secs

secs
------- 
  35856
```